# after a few times the debugging, the breakpoints do not work

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I use the simple code below to login

```java
LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest("093333","ss");
Global.apiManagerTubeless.loginOrRregisterx(loginRequest,new Callback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(response.body());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),getContext().getString(R.string.welcome) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),getContext().getString(R.string.samples) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

When I clone my project from Github,in debug mode  breakpoints work correctly onResponse and OnFailure.
But after a few times the debugging, the breakpoints do not work anymore

Have any solutions?

Comment: Have you checked that might be _onFailure_ executing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is this:
Put breakpoints on Runtime.
Also Can Be Detectable breakpoints Difference Added on Runtime with breakpoint  Inserted Before Run Time:

[image]